# Issue implementing the java Comparable<T> class

Tags: java, class, interface, abstract-class, comparable

The graphic below shows a compilation error involving my `if-else` conditional when attempting to implement the `compareTo()` method located in my `Tool` class. I am uncertain of the issue, as it would appear that the method is `public` and within my `Tool` class (from which the two objects being compared are constructed).

[image: Graphic showing compilation error.]

```
public interface Product {
    public abstract String getName();
    public abstract double getCost();
}

public abstract class Vehicle implements Product {
    private String name;
    private double cost;

    public Vehicle(String name, double cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
    public Car(String s, double d) {
        super(s, d);
    }
}

public class Truck extends Vehicle {
    public Truck(String s, double d) {
        super(s, d);
    }
}

public class Tool implements Product, Comparable<Product> {
    private String name;
    private double cost;

    public Tool(String name, double cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public int compareTo(Product obj) {
        if (getCost() < obj.getCost()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (getCost() == obj.getCost()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

import java.util.*;
public class InventoryDemo
{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
        list.add(new Car("Jagur", 1000000));
        list.add(new Car("Neon", 17000));
        list.add(new Tool("JigSaw", 149.18));
        list.add(new Car("Jaguar", 110000));
        list.add(new Car("Neon", 17500));
        list.add(new Car("Neon", 17875.32));
        list.add(new Truck("RAM", 35700));
        list.add(new Tool("CircularSaw", 200));
        list.add(new Tool("CircularSaw", 150));
        list.add(new Tool("saw1", 200));
        list.add(new Tool("saw2", 150));

        if(list.get(9).compareTo(list.get(10)) == 0) {
            System.out.println("\nThey are the same size using compareTo().");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nThey are not the same size using compareTo().");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a `List` of `Product`. When you do `list.get(9)` you get a `Product` and since you didn't specify that a `Product` is comparable, the compiler doesn't know that such method exists for the underlying implementation of the Product object you get.

Comment: Well, `Product` doesn't implement `Comparable<Product>`, nor does it provide any `compareTo` method.

Comment: @ZouZou `Public class Tool implements Product, Comparable<Product> {` and `public int compareTo(Product obj) {`. I didn't?

Comment: @alx You specify that a `Tool` is comparable. But when doing `list.get(9)` you don't get a `Tool`, you get a `Product`, even if the underlying representation of this `Product` is a `Tool`. Like when you are doing `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();` you cannot call `list.trimToSize()` per example, even if the underlying implementation is an `ArrayList` because the `List` interface doesn't "provide" this method.

Comment: Tool implements Comparable. Product doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I was provided pseudo-code which specified construction of most aspects of the classes--and I followed it pretty precisely. It would appear it was erroneous, though. It works now though. +1'd everyone.

Comment: Jeez, two downvotes on my question. I forgot that this site's community looks down on less-experienced developers.

Comment: @alx Don't care about downvotes. The essential is that you understood your mistake.

Comment: @ZouZou Yeah--it just kinda burns me--the way people behave in this community, sometimes.

Comment: @ZouZou I will admit, though--it's not NEARLY as bad as MathExchange. That place is horrendous for new users. At least here, you almost always get an answer, and there's generally pretty helpful and friendly users amongst the crowd.

Comment: @BheshGurung It does include the exact compiler error. It's at the bottom directly under the message box. :L

Comment: @BheshGurung in fact--it's in the message box, as well.

Comment: @BheshGurung I'd tend to disagree. It shows the exact location in the code of the error, as well as a full description of the error. It saves time, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is your list is of type `List<Product>`, but product does not implement the `Comparable` interface, therefore this type does not implement the method.

Make

```
public interface Product extends Comparable<Product> {
    public abstract String getName();
    public abstract double getCost();
}
```

Comment: just a comment ... mistakes happen in a hurry

Answer (score 1):

Your `Product` interface doesn't extend `Comparable<Product>` which adds

```
int compareTo(Product other);
```

`list` is declared as `ArrayList<Product>`, so `list.get(9)` will return you `Product` object.

To resolve issue you have either to make `Product` extend `Comparable<Product>` and implement method in `Vehicle`, or, maybe, use equals() method instead, overriding default implementation. Actually the second way is preferrable, because `equals()` method checks whether objects are **equal**, while `compareTo()` tells you if **this object is greater then other, or other is greater than this, or none of that is applicable** - which makes `equals()` usage more semantically correct in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Your `list` is an `ArrayList<Product>`, so `list.get(9)` returns a `Product`.

The `compareTo(Product)` method is not defined in interface `Product`. It's defined in class `Tool`, but you're trying to call it on a `Product`, which is not (always) a `Tool`.

To solve this: Make your interface `Product` extend `Comparable<Product>`:

```
interface Product extends Comparable<Product> {
```

Ofcourse that means that any (non-abstract) class that implements interface `Product` must also have a `public int compareTo(Product obj)` method.

Answer (score 1):

The list item you are trying to call compareTo() on is a Product, because the list is declared as a list of Products:

```
ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

When accessing items in the list, Java is only aware that the items implement the Product interface, irrespective of whether the actual class also implements Comparable.

One solution is to define Product as extending Comparable:

```
public interface Product extends Comparable<Product> {
  public abstract String getName();
  public abstract double getCost();
}
```