# Sorting through an ArrayList of objects by an object's given constructor value

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

The focus of my question pertains to the `takeInventory()` method.

You can assume that `InventoryDemo`'s `main()` method is functional (aside the implementation of the `takeInventory()` method).

If you desire, you may find the other classes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697869/issue-implementing-the-java-comparablet-class).

The objective of my `takeInventory()` method is to sort through my `list`, and report the integer value of each unique instance of `Product` types.

This is to be differentiated exclusively by name:

> *Product(**name**, cost)*).

`Product`s of like name should be grouped together (regardless of cost).

The output should report this:

[image: This shows the desired output.]

I assume there is a method of sorting this data which is much more effective than my current approach. However, I do not know of one.

```
import java.util.*;
public class InventoryDemo
{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
        list.add(new Car("Jaguar", 1000000));
        list.add(new Car("Neon", 17000));
        list.add(new Tool("JigSaw", 149.18));
        list.add(new Car("Jaguar", 110000));
        list.add(new Car("Neon", 17500));
        list.add(new Car("Neon", 17875.32));
        list.add(new Truck("RAM", 35700));
        list.add(new Tool("CircularSaw", 200));
        list.add(new Tool("CircularSaw", 150));
        list.add(new Tool("saw1", 200));
        list.add(new Tool("saw2", 150));

        if(list.get(9).compareTo(list.get(10)) == 0) {
            System.out.println("\nBoth saws are of equal value.");
        } else if(list.get(9).compareTo(list.get(10)) > 0) {
            System.out.println("\nThe first saw is more expensive.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nThe second saw is more expensive.");
        }

        takeInventory(list);
    }

    public static void takeInventory(ArrayList<Product> list) {
        int inventory[] = new int[list.size()];
        int counter = 0;
        for(Product token: list) {
            for(int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) {
                if(token.compareTo(list.get(x)) == 0) {
                    inventory[counter] = 0;
                } else {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int token : inventory) {
            System.out.println(token);
        }
    }
}
```

**If it isn't explicitly clear:**

I want a remedy for my `takeInventory()` method. The objective intent of this method is to sort through a given `ArrayList` of objects, and report the sum cost of its unique-type values. This is demonstrated clearly in the output. The last string literal of the output is produced by the conditional in my main() method. The rest is to be produced by the `takeInventory()` method.

I am certain my current `takeInventory()` is **not** working.

Comment: Not clear what you want, please explain

Comment: What is it that you want the takeInventory method to do?

Comment: Are your sure your current approach is working? I think `takeInventory` always prints out zeroes.

Comment: I want a remedy for my `takeInventory()` method. The objective intent of this method is to sort through a given ArrayList of objects, and report the sum cost of its unique-type values. This is demonstrated clearly in the output. The last string literal of the output is produced by the conditional in my `main()` method. The rest is to be produced by the `takeInventory()` method.

Comment: @jonchen902 It throws an error. I am certain it is **not** working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would build a `Map<String, C>` where `C` is a helper class containing the quantity (`int`) and the cost (`double`). Iterate through the product list, and for each product:

- If the name is not in the map, associate the name to `new C(1, cost)`.
- If the name is in the map, increase the quantity associated with the name by `1` and increase the cost associated with the name by `cost`.

Finally, iterate through the map and print the result; then you're done.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Here is some code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Product {
    private String name;
    private double cost;

    public Product (String name, double cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}

class Car extends Product {
    public Car(String name, double cost) {
        super(name, cost);
    }
}

class Truck extends Product {

    public Truck(String name, double cost) {
        super(name, cost);
    }
}

class Tool extends Product {

    public Tool(String name, double cost) {
        super(name, cost);
    }   
}



class Entry {
    private int quantity = 1;
    private double cost;

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public Entry(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public void add (double cost) {
        quantity++;
        this.cost += cost;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("Quantity = " + quantity + ", Total cost = " + cost);
    }
}


public class Inventory {

    static void takeInventory(List<Product> list) {
        Map<String, Entry> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (Product p : list) {
            Entry e = map.get(p.getName());
            if (e == null) {
                map.put(p.getName(), new Entry(p.getCost()));
            } else {
                e.add(p.getCost());
            }
        }

        for (String s : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.print(s);
            Entry e = map.get(s);
            System.out.println(" " + e);            
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
        list.add(new Car("Jaguar", 100000));
        list.add(new Car("Neon", 17000));
        list.add(new Tool("JigSaw", 149.18));
        list.add(new Car("Jaguar", 110000));
        list.add(new Car("Neon", 17500));
        list.add(new Car("Neon", 17875.32));
        list.add(new Truck("RAM", 35700));
        list.add(new Tool("CircularSaw", 200));
        list.add(new Tool("CircularSaw", 150));
        list.add(new Tool("saw1", 200));
        list.add(new Tool("saw2", 150));

        takeInventory(list);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
saw1 Quantity = 1, Total cost = 200.0
saw2 Quantity = 1, Total cost = 150.0
CircularSaw Quantity = 2, Total cost = 350.0
RAM Quantity = 1, Total cost = 35700.0
JigSaw Quantity = 1, Total cost = 149.18
Jaguar Quantity = 2, Total cost = 210000.0
Neon Quantity = 3, Total cost = 52375.32
```

Comment: Could you provide an example section of code? I've never used a `Map()`.

Comment: This is an effective fix. I'm still a little shaky on the concepts of the fix, but I'll just have to read into it a bit more. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Zoyd's answer, you could have a `Map<String, List<Product>>` and then just add each product into the map like this:

```
Map<String, List<Product>> productMap = new HashMap<>();
for(Product product : list) {
    if (!productMap.containsKey(product.getName())) {
        productMap.put(product.getName(), new ArrayList<Product>());
    }
    productMap.get(product.getName()).add(product);
}
```

Then in your print method you can just iterate through the map keyset and add up all the product costs in each list like this:

```
for(String productName : productMap.keySet()) {
    List<Product> products = productMap.get(productName);
    int quantity = products.size();
    double totalCost = 0.0;
    for (Product product : products) {
        totalCost += product.getCost();
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("%s: Quantity = %s, Total cost = %s", productName, quantity, totalCost));
}
```

Comment: How would I produce the output in my given graphic? I'm not familiar with these methods and their iteration.

Comment: You missed a `)` after your `if` condition.

Comment: I would use `LinkedHashMap` to make the output order more reasonable. And I prefer a single statement: 
`productMap.forEach((a, b) -> System.out.println(a + " Quantity = "
+ b.size() + ", Total cost = "
+ b.stream().mapToDouble(Product::getCost).sum()));`

Answer (score 0):

So a clean way to do this is to use one of Guava's FluentIterable, which is googles class for filtering sets according to some rule. First make a predicate to define your sort:

```
class sorter implements Predicate<Product> {
    private final String name;
    sorter(String name){
        this.name=name
    }
    @Override
    boolean apply(Product input){
        return (input.name == this.name)
    }
}
```

This will return true if input.name is the same as the name given to the predicate. This works with Guava's fluentIterable class to return all the elements where the predicate is true. E.g.

```
List<Product> cars = FluentIterable.from(list).filter(new sorter("car"))
```

Will produce a list of all the elements which have name "car".

Since you will iterate once for each name it might have performance issues on large sets, on the other hand, since its all read only and does not mutate the list, you could easily multithread it locally.

It is very easy to read/maintainable though.